# React-native-macos child_process removed from npm for security reasons

Tags: javascript, react-native, shell, child-process, react-native-macos

I tried to install `child_process`, but I noticed there is nothing in the `node_modules` folder.

I went looking on npm and saw this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/child_process

It seems to have been removed for security reasons, what can I use to do the same thing on `react-native-macos`?